# PSR coding standard - PHP

Tags: php

just developed a simple CLI php code that calculates the multiplication table of your choosen size but when I check the files to make sure they stick to PSR coding standards, it gives me four errors/violations. I don't know where in the files the errors are after several attempts and  days of work on the files.

there are two files:
cliVersion.php and generateCLITable.php

The first file gives me 1 PSR error and the second one gives me 3 PSR errors.

this is how I generate the multiplication table of size 12 on command line :

- php cliVersion.php 12

can anyone help me to find out the PSR errors in the files.

here's the files and the error report:

## cliVersion.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

require_once 'generateCLITable.php';
require_once '../model/validateInput.php';
?>

<?php

// Assign the user's input argument value to $input variable
$inputString = $argv[1];

$errorMessage = "Please enter a valid argument (a whole number greater than 1)";


// Check if the user's input argument is not null or empty
if ($inputString == null || $inputString == "") {
    echo $errorMessage;
} else {

    // Create an object of ValidateInput Class
    $inputData = new ValidateInput();

    /*
     Validate the $input variable received from the user as an argument.
     The code will be safe to be processed after this line.
    */
    $validatedInput = $inputData->validateInputData($inputString);
    $validatedInputInt = (int)$validatedInput;

    /*
     Check if the validated input is an Integer and if it is,
     generates the table else returns the error message
    */
    $isInputValidInt = $inputData->isInputInt($validatedInputInt);

    if ($isInputValidInt && $validatedInputInt > 1) {
        $multTable = new MultTable();
        $multTable->generateTable($validatedInputInt);
    } else {
        echo $errorMessage;
    }
}

echo PHP_EOL;
```

## GenerateCLITable.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

class MultTable
{
    /**
     * The public generateTable function generates the multiplication table
     *
     * @param int $inputValue
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function generateTable(int $inputValue)
    {

        // Create first row of table headers - green colour
        for ($col=1; $col <= $inputValue; $col++) {
            echo "\033[35m \t$col \033[0m";
        }
        // Create remaining rows
        for ($row=1, $col=1; $row <= $inputValue; $row++) {
            echo "\n";
            // First cell is a table header - green colour
            if ($col == 1) {
                echo "\033[35m \n$row \033[0m";
            }
            while ($col <= $inputValue) {
                echo "\t" . $row * $col++ ;
            }
            // Reset $col at the end of the row
            $col = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

## Error report:

```
cliVersion.php
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 1 ERROR AFFECTING 1 LINE

generateCLITable.php
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 3 ERRORS AFFECTING 3 LINES
```

Comment: Have you tried [PHPCS](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer)?

Comment: I've tried that and when I fix the errors and run another test it gives me 4 more unidentified errors

Comment: I just added the link to the files if you can have a look please. many thanks

Comment: Use a better code sniffer that actually tells you what and where the issues are. Try something like https://packagist.org/packages/squizlabs/php_codesniffer. That package will tell you what the issues are and what lines they're at.

Comment: Thanks Magnus, I have tried phpcs and fixed the errors but then my professor said you have 17 errors now. so he said my original files which I have uploaded above had only 4 errors but after fixing the errors with phpcs they went up to 17 errors. I am just confused where the errors are.

Comment: If you use php_codesniffer in PSR-2 mode and it doesn't report any errors, then I would argue that your professor probably aren't using PSR-2. Isn't he telling you what the errors actually are? However, from the code above, I do see some issues. 1. In a code block (class, function, loops, if-statements) there shouldn't be any empy lines between the control structure and the code. You have that in the beginning of your class method and in your `else`-block. Also, all files must have an empty line in the end.

Comment: no. he's just telling me the number of errors I've got each time I redo the codes. there is an empty line at the end of the files but is doesn't show here. I'll give the else statement a try. have you got any other ideas where the errors might be?!

Comment: ...also remember that you need to consistently have 4 spaces instead of tabs. Anyway, use the library I suggested. If that gives you no errors, then I would definitely challenge the professor.

Comment: Thank you very much Magnus.much appreciated. I will use the library and pass the code to my proffesor. do you have any ideas how I can challenge him as I asked him for some advice and he said I have to find the erorrs myself.

Comment: You could say that you've run several code sniffers that all claim that the code is OK, so that you would need to know what isn't according to him. I mean, he's there to teach you, right? So just saying "nope, do it again" isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: I have to admit that I feel your problems run deeper than PSR. I like your attn to detail in checking values and such and comments but I think you need to focus on some things which I have pointed out in my comments. Please take no offense to this, I am only pointing out my thoughts on improvement ...

Comment: Thanks Magnus. I will do the changes accordingly and will get back to you with his feedback.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I'll change the code the way you pointed out and will see what he's got to say

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer in such cases.

Comment: I used that and fixed all the errors but when I passed the code to my professor, he said I still have 4 errors in two files. I have uploaded the files and provided a link for that if anyone can have a look and help. Thanks

Comment: Ah so that was academic assignment? If you were given which PSR's you need to validate against, you need to configure PHPCSFixer to update the code to them, they are not all automatically applied.

Comment: Thanks, where and how can I change the phpcsfixer configuration?

Comment: All should go into a `.php_cs` file. See https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer#config-file for more details

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to unit test the code. I would probably focus on trying to be as thoughtful with the code first . Take cliVersion, I think you can simplify it greatly by creating a single method to handle the input. Also I find a lot of issue with your comments and variables and overdesign.

[image: comments]

Revised Version:

```
<?php
//declare(strict_types=1); // I'm using php 5 so I don't have this (but ok for you)
require_once 'generateCLITable.php';
require_once '../model/validateInput.php';

$must_be_gtr_than = 1; // set floor val for validation
$inputData = new ValidateInput($must_be_gtr_than);
$multTable = new MultTable();

if ($inputData->isValidIntegerData($argv[1])) {
    $tableSize = (int) $argv[1];
    $multTable->generateTable($tableSize);
} else {
    echo "Error: Please enter a valid argument (a whole number greater than ".$must_be_gtr_than.")";
    die();
}
```

In this example I have one method alone that validates that I have an integer > 0, if isValidIntegerData than proceed . Think about ease of code and names that make sense generateTable doesn't tell me much, is there a better name ? Things like that. Take "$validatedInputInt", that doesn't speak to what you are doing as well as what that int is, "tableSize" makes more sense to me. Also we many times save camel back for Classes etc.. I would look up PSR2.

For example we use

```
CONST_SOMETHING  = xx; //constants
var_x or varx // lowercase for vars
methodX  //camel back 
ClassName // ucwords for classes 
etc..
```

UPDATE:
This is how I would probably go about building something like this:

```
<?php
//declare(strict_types=1); // PHP5.x Example

class GenerateCLITable
{
    const DEFAULT_BOARD_SIZE = 12;
    public $game_board, $table_size;

    public function __construct($input = self::DEFAULT_BOARD_SIZE)
    {
        $this->game_board = $this->generateTable($input);
    }

    public function generateTable($inputValue = self::DEFAULT_BOARD_SIZE)
    {
        $table = "";
        // Create first row of table headers - green colour
        for ($col=1; $col <= $inputValue; $col++) {
            $table .= "\033[35m \t$col \033[0m";
        }
        // Create remaining rows
        for ($row=1, $col=1; $row <= $inputValue; $row++) {
            $table .= "\n";
            // First cell is a table header - green colour
            if ($col == 1) {
                $table .= "\033[35m \n$row \033[0m";
            }
            while ($col <= $inputValue) {
                $table .=  "\t" . $row * $col++ ;
            }
            // Reset $col at the end of the row
            $col = 1;
        }
        $this->game_board = $table;
        $this->table_size = $inputValue;
        return $table;
    }

    public function isValidInputValue($input = '', $size = 0)
    {
        return (!empty($input) && $input > $size) ? (is_int((int) $input)) : false;
    }

}

//require_once 'generateCLITable.php';
$multTable = new GenerateCLITable();
$must_be_gtr_than = 1;

if (!$multTable->isValidInputValue($argv[1], $must_be_gtr_than)) {
    echo "Error: Please enter a valid argument (a whole number greater than ".$must_be_gtr_than.")";
    die();
}
$table = $multTable->generateTable((int) $argv[1]);
echo $table . "\n";
```

Comment: Many thanks Mike. much appreciated. I take notes and fix my code.

Comment: could you check the PSR errors I'm getting on these codes as well please and see where they are?

Comment: I am seeing errors about new lines and spaces, minor stuff. Honestly you REALLY should focus on the code. Set up an IDE such as PHP Storm to default to PSR2. I inserted your code, selected reformat code and putt in WCS and it gave me more errors because we use "tabs".  Anyway, this is all minor stuff focus on your naming , labeling vars, and when comments should be used and you will come a long way. Like I said, your code is good, but it's overwrought.

Comment: @MasoudRousta . like I said in the previous post, to me declaring "$multTable = new MultTable();" only sometimes is very bad practice and your worse offense because it would to me be necessary for your application

Comment: I see more issues as I go, for example, you need to name your class the same as your file. I provided a sample of how one could do this as an improvement, I hope you take no offense and maybe vote my answer ..

Comment: Thanks Mike. I really appreciate your help. please show mr a sample so that I know ehat I need to do in future.

Comment: I included it in my post above under UPDATE: I placed everything in a single file , but you would keep the class in it's own file

Comment: Sorry, I have less than 15 reputation and it doesn't let me do it. Thanks a lot for all your help.I promise I will give you a point as soon as I earn more reputation